# use the select2 boxes value to filter table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, jquery-select2

I am trying to filter a table using multiple select2 boxes.

```js
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
  jQuery('.js-example-basic-multiple').on("select2:select", function(e) {
    var loc = $('.js-example-basic-multiple').val();
    jQuery('#events-table td.hidden-location').removeClass('hidden-location');
    jQuery('#events-table td:not(".' + loc + '")').addClass('hidden-location');
    if (loc == 'all') {
      jQuery('#events-table tr').removeClass('hidden-location');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 300px;
}

tr {
  background: white;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.hidden-location {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple>
  <optgroup label="CS">
    <option value="MSC5-x">MSC5</option>
    <option value="MSC6-x">MSC6</option>
    <option value="MSC7-x">MSC7</option>
    <option value="MSC8-x">MSC8</option>
    <option value="MSC9-x">MSC9</option>
    <option value="MSC10-x">MSC10</option>

  </optgroup>
</select>

<table id="events-table" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>MSC5</th>
      <th>MSC6</th>
      <th>MSC7</th>
      <th>MSC8</th>
      <th>MSC9</th>
      <th>MSC10</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="MSC5-x">X</td>
      <td class="MSC6-x">X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="MSC5-x">X</td>
      <td class="MSC6-x">X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="MSC5-x">X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="MSC10-x">X</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="MSC5-x">X</td>
      <td class="MSC6-x">X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="MSC9-x">X</td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="MSC6-x">X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="MSC8-x">X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

and now I want to use the multiple selected value to filter an external table, seems not working properly, please check on this site [example](https://jsfiddle.net/5202jsax/92/) instead of the below one, may the jsfiddle can present my question more clear
how i can fix this issue?

just modified something, seems better, but still not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

First use jquery cdn link than use this file /select2.min.js and in last use jquery function.